# Select many columns and other non-continuous columns to find duplicate?

Tags: sas, proc-sql, datastep

I have a dataset with many columns like this:

```
ID  Indicator Name   C1 C2 C3....C90
 A    0001    Black   0  1  1.....0
 B    0001    Blue    1  0  0.....1
 B    0002    Blue    1  0  0.....1
```

Some of the IDs are duplicates because the indicator is different, but they're essentially the same record.  To find duplicates, I want to select distinct ID, Name and then C1 through C90 to check because some claims who have the same Id and indicator have different C1...C90 values.

Is there a way to select c1...c90 either through proc sql or a sas data step?  It seems the only way I can think of is to set the dataset and then drop the non essential columns, but in the actual dataset, it's not only Indicator but at least 15 other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if `PROC SQL` used the `:` variable name wildcard like other Procs do. When no other alternative is reasonable, I usually use a macro to select bulk columns. This might work for you:

```
%macro sel_C(n);
    %do i=1 %to %eval(&n.-1);
        C&i.,
    %end;
    C&n.
%mend sel_C;
proc sql;
    select ID,
           Indicator,
           Name,
           %sel_C(90)
    from have_data;
quit;
```

Comment: I never knew you could select bulk columns using a macro, this is very helpful!

Comment: Awesome! Good luck PinkyL!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, the easiest way would be to concatenate the columns to one.  RETAIN that value from row to row, and you can compare it across rows to see if it's the same or not.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id indicator;
  retain last_cols;
  length last_cols $500;
  cols = catx('|',of c1-c90);
  if first.id then call missing(last_cols);
  else do;
    identical = (cols = last_cols); *or whatever check you need to perform;
  end;
  output;
  last_cols = cols;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do this and it will be much easier if the actual column names are `C1 - C90`. If you're just looking to remove anything that you know is a duplicate you can use `proc sort`.

```
proc sort data=dups out=nodups nodupkey;
by ID Name C1-C90;
run;
```

The nodupkey option will automatically remove any duplicates in the `by` statement.

Alternatively, if you want to know which records contain duplicates, you could use `proc summary`.

```
proc summary data=dups nway missing;
class ID Name C1-C90;
output out=onlydups(where=(_freq_ > 1));
run;
```

`proc summary` creates two new variables, `_type_` and `_freq_`. If you specify `_freq_ > 1` you will only output the duplicate records. Also, note that this will remove the `Indicator` variable.